# Very inconsistent msvc behaviour of constexpr bool checks inside lambda

Tags: c++, visual-studio, lambda, c++20, constexpr

I implemented some variadic template functions that work on containers recursively. Consider this basic example:

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept Iteratable = requires(const T n) {
    n.cbegin();
    n.cend();
};
template<typename T>
concept Arithmetic = (std::is_arithmetic_v<T>);

template<typename T, typename U>
concept Same = (std::is_same_v<T, U>);


template<typename... Args>
void foo(Args&&... args) {
    constexpr auto unpack = [&]<typename T>(T value) {
        if constexpr (Iteratable<T>) {
            for (auto i : value) {
                foo(i);
            }
        }
        else if constexpr (Arithmetic<T> && Same<T, int>) {
            std::cout << value << " is an int\n";
        }
        else if constexpr (Arithmetic<T> && Same<T, double>) {
            std::cout << value << " is a double\n";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << value << " is something else\n";
        }
    };

    (unpack(args), ...);
}

int main() {
    foo(1, 4, std::vector{ 5.3, 6.7, 7.8 }, std::array{ std::array{ 100 } });
}
```

this works very well and gives the output:

```
1 is an int
4 is an int
5.3 is a double
6.7 is a double
7.8 is a double
100 is an int
```

and now here is `bar`, which has the exact same logic, except it uses `constexpr bool` functions instead of Concepts:

```cpp
template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_iteratable() { return Iteratable<T>; }

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_arithmetic() { return std::is_arithmetic_v<T>; }

template<typename T, typename U>
constexpr bool is_same() { return std::is_same_v<T, U>; }

template<typename... Args>
void bar(Args&&... args) {
    constexpr auto unpack = [&]<typename T>(T value) {
        if constexpr (is_iteratable<T>()) {
            for (auto i : value) {
                bar(i);
            }
        }
        else if constexpr (is_arithmetic<T>() && is_same<T, int>()) {
            std::cout << value << " is an int\n";
        }
        else if constexpr (is_arithmetic<T>() && is_same<T, double>()) {
            std::cout << value << " is a double\n";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << value << " is something else\n";
        }
    };

    (unpack(args), ...);
}

int main() {
    bar(1, 4, std::vector{ 5.3, 6.7, 7.8 }, std::array{ std::array{ 100 } });
}
```

clang and gcc compile this, but msvc gives these errors on the line where `bar` is declared:

```
C2059   syntax error: ')'
C2143   syntax error: missing ')' before ';'
C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before ')'
```

(for any on msvc godbolt version I checked it fails, but my work setup is for Visual Studio 2022, 17.0.0 Preview 4.0 /std:c++20).

---

The weird thing is, I was using these lambdas with `if constexpr (bool)` for months without any problems, but certain arrangements cause it to suddenly fail with this very ambiguous error. To show this inconsistent behaviour consider `foobar` which uses a mix of Concepts and `constexpr bool` checks:

```cpp
template<typename... Args>
void foobar(Args&&... args) {
    constexpr auto unpack = [&]<typename T>(T value) {
        if constexpr (Iteratable<T>) {
            for (auto i : value) {
                foobar(i);
            }
        }
        else if constexpr (is_arithmetic<T>() && is_same<T, int>()) {
            std::cout << value << " is an int\n";
        }
        else if constexpr (is_arithmetic<T>() && is_same<T, double>()) {
            std::cout << value << " is a double\n";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << value << " is something else\n";
        }
    };

    (unpack(args), ...);
}
```

this fails to compile. But if I remove the `else if constexpr (is_arithmetic<T>() && is_same<T, double>()) ...` statement:

```cpp
template<typename... Args>
void foobar2(Args&&... args) {
    constexpr auto unpack = [&]<typename T>(T value) {
        if constexpr (Iteratable<T>) {
            for (auto i : value) {
                foobar2(i);
            }
        }
        else if constexpr (is_arithmetic<T>() && is_same<T, int>()) {
            std::cout << value << " is an int\n";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << value << " is something else\n";
        }
    };

    (unpack(args), ...);
}
```

it compiles now.

Changing more things, like having an extra `if, else if` inside an `if` sometimes causes it to fail again or replacing a `constexpr bool` check with the corresponding `std::` version causes it to work a gain etc. The whole thing is so broken and random. This has to be a bug, right? My workaround is to only use concepts for now...

Try it out:

- [MSVC](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEElwAbKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2B/ilpGQIhYZEsMXFcibaY9o4CQgRMxATZPn4BdpgOmQ1NBMUR0bHxSQqNza25HeP9oYNlw5UJAJS2qF7EyOwc5gDMocjeWADUJrtuTmPEmKxn2CYaAIJ7B0eYp%2BcKVzcsdw/PZn2DEOXhOZzcADcukRiH8ni9gW8Pm4msQmABPOHPJ4ETAsZIGXHggjo5KMVjvAAqWLQwMwyQIxwAkri0Y0ovQPgARY7XACOXjw1wUEFpY2OlOODGWpwA7FZ4RoAJwMAB0yBiwFCEGWZwV2JV6tcOr1/xMsq5ppxeIJTCJ5xJZOYbAlNIEWwZx0exEICDYjmQ3OOEDG6BAIDwCgA%2Bk1ff68MgoxDwdTdthdbt9f9cfjCZhiaTyS7KaRjo6i%2B85G66Z6hBSgyGCGGI9GFBSkynS1W0xms4rHjnbfa3OXnVTq2NMKpksRjlFUJ5jpGo4RYnamBzMDq5RZeZgCBsGMzWevNym/pm5Zb%2B4O8wWnfXU/cnmLcdPZ/PF8vYwQ/fuE9u5q7tcB7EEeobht%2BPq/vGibJucT56leZrWrmdr5g6hZjhKpajvW3bPo8r5TjOc4LrQS6thSgHynuoHgU2kFUWwHYIV2F67ua17Yjx2Y2nemEPmwqoiV6xDAAoWIQqgeDoMc/CoBA3oSeYCSqSJqrHE0EkykBKFKsR75aV4RDHF4DDJEwyAANZBiYACsVhmGp9mWoJFaummECShCYheJgunyvpDxKngVDHIZpEQCya7svQ549juwXKiF/CzhATAmagS7HCAxy%2Bd4AVJYqSohWVyoKRAeC9slpUpRatVcbVNRKEu4WRel3pxv%2BpgIXcpzOapxx1mwnZLoIdyBX2dUzRBKDrIy4LgvlfnvEt5wDWYlFaUeoQEA5bgMOYZhWgaZUNSVIUte8YURQIk5GUp0F/gGCXYANanOccYBgCNGFuCW437YlemXSlypzWgJnIstBX%2BTDG3HdtTDHOg6xnvZh3Had5WlRdZ3KtdxUE7NjHzdD61uCthUI1TSORscCioP6CChMAxzXQdR1mCdmaNfj51uX2BoQOZlk2Rl4kKKsxwaTV8IC6hQ7/Xhwmicpklpv80myXOTRPSpg3ORpWlS1N%2BkdcZpli1ZtlnDyDlOS5bkjlhj53N51P%2BebYOhe191vlFy6rmyG7xX1XnLD7JOpSQwaZaZeC5V7RWgzH4NKlE%2BvVTjGeC/z3G40Tt2W1V0Y/i9CZvYBRsJJRUZtqNbFAx7UfE7jIWQwttMpz39MKDtLeY9zvPTfnvvF/7DAPUH5fPbB1e6bX31gMujf/YDe2t9HHcQ2TUOLecsOrX3PPI6j6PxcP2N877TUT7QrVp7vSpdxTR8bXDa0f3TZ8M0zLM2Yc0fvma%2BPNc4zXvmdBqt9eLKlFhZW2ksdKljljjRWPFbzoXvBWE2GspIyTkgpLOxADaSVribbS0t27KktgnbKNsbJ2UcqpByLtVbji8j5VaO8M4lwDiRdKMVQ5ngjumGhkCKpxwyllHKeUv68MkTNYh2d5bpzxoXPOisZqTzutPQO6UoLdVemImun065rwpGNLekdFG4zfofNwx8aaU02sjXaE0wGjwLs1EBbU9Ez0MXPYxVdTFL3MfXdeY00ZeFEdgHUdiM4OJ7l/U%2BW0GYoxiRjLG4DYEd20VdPxz88572bAfFJJ9XH90ZszfcrMjDAKUFzG%2BY96qaI0bnEWjDrLIOlqgkSaioF8TQsODheCpYEN1io4gZgyGsONqJKhii6GyO6cwp2bCcHYSfJ7BREiQr8P0YI4MwjTzhwBpNfZGc0rx1kUneRPCrlKOmbMnOeSSkdLvgUwmfjDmBODEYmCPVF4fSGpYpuANSw2PiW3YpSjkmuNSVUv%2BA9DBDxyd4r57TClPyCnfUp4ZymIsqT/Nx/9am/iAZzLxEDx7QKFihLpiCJZLP6aqQZGC9rHBYEwbUijKpcFLNIRmZMoQOBIEBY49lSxJGOLKK8pY5qogxJKpVxA0SYlolwDQGgrxXkGcqEhEBBXHGFXNMVMJJXSuOLK%2BVXFFVk2VZq3caqNWSu1bqri%2BqIHTONUKh1zYLUStota21CqRXNidaqx16qVVap1XqriBqlQvL9aagN4Yg2whDTK0sdqLQZpAFG2irq427g9Ymi0HKuQcFWLQTg9leB%2BA4FoUgqBOBOMsNYGpGwtgDV2DwUgBBNC1tWNZEA9kNCqiVFIAAHJIHVs7ZRcCVLsDQ0h60cEkE2kdbbOC8AUCADQQ6R2rDgLAJAaB8R0FiOQSgV7kg3riBCZAyRkhJhXVGPMYwoyqASNIGgtBWSHogFEXdURQhNHRJwQdV62CCAAPIMFoNBltvAsA8qMOINDpB8DXG6FCQ9OGpxdBMtsQde0agwd4LQPAUQ0TEHRB4LA1Gh0%2BhYKevgBgJIADU8CYAAO4IadKx/gggRBiHYFIGQghFAqHUDh3QgqDBGBQNYaw%2Bg6OHtgGOEAaIjCYAUBCXYpAoRxAIMQcy1ko5toZJkIjAB6CCpgu2WDMK2zo3RnAQFcJMPwgrghzFKOUPQqR0h1CyJ4NooWCgRYGMFxY1Rag9BmH5vQnmIu9GaPFoYFRbCpai7kQVYw%2Bg5YWBUVYTNe1SbY5gcjtb9ANp3Th9tHA/2SG5UZwMEIV2qm/YyCAnanI2GOLgQgcc9gmo8Ne%2Bgs5JvLF4MOtDNnx2SCVKqDQs77JcHskqGdZhZ0aASEqJIm7t2kGba21rB6j0nuW3WzgZheAcY9Rd3d127taBs2Z9IzhJBAA)
- [GCC](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEElwAbKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2B/ilpGQIhYZEsMXFcibaY9o4CQgRMxATZPn4BdpgOmQ1NBMUR0bHxSQqNza25HeP9oYNlw5UJAJS2qF7EyOwc5gDMocjeWADUJrtuTmPEmKxn2CYaAIJ7B0eYp%2BcKVzcsdw/PZn2DEOXhOZzcADcukRiH8ni9gW8Pm4msQmABPOHPJ4ETAsZIGXHggjo5KMVjvAAqWLQwMwyQIxwAkri0Y0ovQPgARY7XACOXjw1wUEFpY2OlOODGWpwA7FZ4RoAJwMAB0yBiwFCEGWZwV2JV6tcOr1/xMsq5ppxeIJTCJ5xJZOYbAlNIEWwZx0exEICDYjmQ3OOEDG6BAIDwCgA%2Bk1ff68MgoxDwdTdthdbt9f9cfjCZhiaTyS7KaRjo6i%2B85G66Z6hBSgyGCGGI9GFBSkynS1W0xms4rHjnbfa3OXnVTq2NMKpksRjlFUJ5jpGo4RYnamBzMDq5RZeZgCBsGMzWevNym/pm5Zb%2B4O8wWnfXU/cnmLcdPZ/PF8vYwQ/fuE9u5q7tcB7EEeobht%2BPq/vGibJucT56leZrWrmdr5g6hZjhKpajvW3bPo8r5TjOc4LrQS6thSgHynuoHgU2kFUWwHYIV2F67ua17Yjx2Y2nemEPmwqoiV6xDAAoWIQqgeDoMc/CoBA3oSeYCSqSJqrHE0EkykBKFKsR75aV4RDHF4DDJEwyAANZBiYACsVhmGp9mWoJFaummECShCYheJgunyvpDxKngVDHIZpEQCya7svQ549juwXKiF/CzhATAmagS7HCAxy%2Bd4AVJYqSohWVyoKRAeC9slpUpRatVcbVNRKEu4WRel3pxv%2BpgIXcpzOapxx1mwnZLoIdyBX2dUzRBKDrIy4LgvlfnvEt5wDWYlFaUeoQEA5bgMOYZhWgaZUNSVIUte8YURQIk5GUp0F/gGCXYANanOccYBgCNGFuCW437YlemXSlypzWgJnIstBX%2BTDG3HdtTDHOg6xnvZh3Had5WlRdZ3KtdxUE7NjHzdD61uCthUI1TSORscCioP6CChMAxzXQdR1mCdmaNfj51uX2BoQOZlk2Rl4kKKsxwaTV8IC6hQ7/Xhwmicpklpv80myXOTRPSpg3ORpWlS1N%2BkdcZpli1ZtlnDyDlOS5bkjlhj53N51P%2BebYOhe191vlFy6rmyG7xX1XnLD7JOpSQwaZaZeC5V7RWgzH4NKlE%2BvVTjGeC/z3G40Tt2W1V0Y/i9CZvYBRsJJRUZtqNbFAx7UfE7jIWQwttMpz39MKDtLeY9zvPTfnvvF/7DAPUH5fPbB1e6bX31gMujf/YDe2t9HHcQ2TUOLecsOrX3PPI6j6PxcP2N877TUT7QrVp7vSpdxTR8bXDa0f3TZ8M0zLM2Yc0fvma%2BPNc4zXvmdBqt9eLKlFhZW2ksdKljljjRWPFbzoXvBWE2GspIyTkgpLOxADaSVribbS0t27KktgnbKNsbJ2UcqpByLtVbji8j5VaO8M4lwDiRdKMVQ5ngjumGhkCKpxwyllHKeUv68MkTNYh2d5bpzxoXPOisZqTzutPQO6UoLdVemImun065rwpGNLekdFG4zfofNwx8aaU02sjXaE0wGjwLs1EBbU9Ez0MXPYxVdTFL3MfXdeY00ZeFEdgHUdiM4OJ7l/U%2BW0GYoxiRjLG4DYEd20VdPxz88572bAfFJJ9XH90ZszfcrMjDAKUFzG%2BY96qaI0bnEWjDrLIOlqgkSaioF8TQsODheCpYEN1io4gZgyGsONqJKhii6GyO6cwp2bCcHYSfJ7BREiQr8P0YI4MwjTzhwBpNfZGc0rx1kUneRPCrlKOmbMnOeSSkdLvgUwmfjDmBODEYmCPVF4fSGpYpuANSw2PiW3YpSjkmuNSVUv%2BA9DBDxyd4r57TClPyCnfUp4ZymIsqT/Nx/9am/iAZzLxEDx7QKFihLpiCJZLP6aqQZGC9rHBYEwbUijKpcFLNIRmZMoQOBIEBY49lSxJGOLKK8pY5qogxJKpVxA0SYlolwDQGgrxXkGcqEhEBBXHGFXNMVMJJXSuOLK%2BVXFFVk2VZq3caqNWSu1bqri%2BqIHTONUKh1zYLUStota21CqRXNidaqx16qVVap1XqriBqlQvL9aagN4Yg2whDTK0sdqLQZpAFG2irq427g9Ymi0HKuQcFWLQTg9leB%2BA4FoUgqBOBOMsNYGpGwtgDV2DwUgBBNC1tWNZEA9kNCqiVFIAAHJIHVs7ZRcCVLsDQ0h60cEkE2kdbbOC8AUCADQQ6R2rDgLAJAaB8R0FiOQSgV7kg3riMASoAQaC0FZIeiAURd1RFCE0dEnBB1XrYIIAA8gwWggGW28CwDyow4gYOkHwNcboUJD1IanF0Ey2xB17RqEB3gtA8BRDRMQdEHgsCEaHT6Fgp6%2BAGAkgANTwJgAA7mBp01H%2BCCBEGIdgUgZCCEUCodQSHdCCoMEYFA1hrD6BI4e2AY4QBoiMJgBQEJdikChHEAgxBzLWSjm2hkmQMMAFpQz21MF2ywZgmAHpqNCTILgGDuE8G0PQwQ5ilHKHoVI6Q6hZHc7kQV/nCgMAGD5xY1Rag9BmJMPwgrOjdHqDMSLQwKi2Hi8FxLWW%2BjpYWBUVYTNe0CZo5gXDtb9ANp3Uh9tHBVCzoSGZhIkhjjAGQIGSoqotoQE7U5GwxxcCEDjnsE1Hhr30FnGN5YvBh0waM%2BOyQSpVQaFnfZLg9klQzrMLOjQCQlRJE3du0gzbW31YPUek9C262cDMLwOjHrTu7ou9drQRmdPpGcJIIAA%3D)
- [Clang](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEElwAbKQADqgKhE4MHt6%2B/ilpGQIhYZEsMXFcibaY9o4CQgRMxATZPn4BdpgOmQ1NBMUR0bHxSQqNza25HeP9oYNlw5UJAJS2qF7EyOwc5gDMocjeWADUJrtuTmPEmKxn2CYaAIJ7B0eYp%2BcKVzcsdw/PZn2DEOXhOZzcADcukRiH8ni9gW8Pm4msQmABPOHPJ4ETAsZIGXHggjo5KMVjvAAqWLQwMwyQIxwAkri0Y0ovQPgARY7XACOXjw1wUEFpY2OlOODGWpwA7FZ4RoAJwMAB0yBiwFCEGWZwV2JV6tcOr1/xMsq5ppxeIJTCJ5xJZOYbAlNIEWwZx0exEICDYjmQ3OOEDG6BAIDwCgA%2Bk1ff68MgoxDwdTdthdbt9f9cfjCZhiaTyS7KaRjo6i%2B85G66Z6hBSgyGCGGI9GFBSkynS1W0xms4rHjnbfa3OXnVTq2NMKpksRjlFUJ5jpGo4RYnamBzMDq5RZeZgCBsGMzWevNym/pm5Zb%2B4O8wWnfXU/cnmLcdPZ/PF8vYwQ/fuE9u5q7tcB7EEeobht%2BPq/vGibJucT56leZrWrmdr5g6hZjhKpajvW3bPo8r5TjOc4LrQS6thSgHynuoHgU2kFUWwHYIV2F67ua17Yjx2Y2nemEPmwqoiV6xDAAoWIQqgeDoMc/CoBA3oSeYCSqSJqrHE0EkykBKFKsR75aV4RDHF4DDJEwyAANZBiYACsVhmGp9mWoJFaummECShCYheJgunyvpDxKngVDHIZpEQCya7svQ549juwXKiF/CzhATAmagS7HCAxy%2Bd4AVJYqSohWVyoKRAeC9slpUpRatVcbVNRKEu4WRel3pxv%2BpgIXcpzOapxx1mwnZLoIdyBX2dUzRBKDrIy4LgvlfnvEt5wDWYlFaUeoQEA5bgMOYZhWgaZUNSVIUte8YURQIk5GUp0F/gGCXYANanOccYBgCNGFuCW437YlemXSlypzWgJnIstBX%2BTDG3HdtTDHOg6xnvZh3Had5WlRdZ3KtdxUE7NjHzdD61uCthUI1TSORscCioP6CChMAxzXQdR1mCdmaNfj51uX2BoQOZlk2Rl4kKKsxwaTV8IC6hQ7/Xhwmicpklpv80myXOTRPSpg3ORpWlS1N%2BkdcZpli1ZtlnDyDlOS5bkjlhj53N51P%2BebYOhe191vlFy6rmyG7xX1XnLD7JOpSQwaZaZeC5V7RWgzH4NKlE%2BvVTjGeC/z3G40Tt2W1V0Y/i9CZvYBRsJJRUZtqNbFAx7UfE7jIWQwttMpz39MKDtLeY9zvPTfnvvF/7DAPUH5fPbB1e6bX31gMujf/YDe2t9HHcQ2TUOLecsOrX3PPI6j6PxcP2N877TUT7QrVp7vSpdxTR8bXDa0f3TZ8M0zLM2Yc0fvma%2BPNc4zXvmdBqt9eLKlFhZW2ksdKljljjRWPFbzoXvBWE2GspIyTkgpLOxADaSVribbS0t27KktgnbKNsbJ2UcqpByLtVbji8j5VaO8M4lwDiRdKMVQ5ngjumGhkCKpxwyllHKeUv68MkTNYh2d5bpzxoXPOisZqTzutPQO6UoLdVemImun065rwpGNLekdFG4zfofNwx8aaU02sjXaE0wGjwLs1EBbU9Ez0MXPYxVdTFL3MfXdeY00ZeFEdgHUdiM4OJ7l/U%2BW0GYoxiRjLG4DYEd20VdPxz88572bAfFJJ9XH90ZszfcrMjDAKUFzG%2BY96qaI0bnEWjDrLIOlqgkSaioF8TQsODheCpYEN1io4gZgyGsONqJKhii6GyO6cwp2bCcHYSfJ7BREiQr8P0YI4MwjTzhwBpNfZGc0rx1kUneRPCrlKOmbMnOeSSkdLvgUwmfjDmBODEYmCPVF4fSGpYpuANSw2PiW3YpSjkmuNSVUv%2BA9DBDxyd4r57TClPyCnfUp4ZymIsqT/Nx/9am/iAZzLxEDx7QKFihLpiCJZLP6aqQZGC9rHBYEwbUijKpcFLNIRmZMoQOBIEBY49lSxJGOLKK8pY5qogxJKpVxA0SYlolwDQGgrxXkGcqEhEBBXHGFXNMVMJJXSuOLK%2BVXFFVk2VZq3caqNWSu1bqri%2BqIHTONUKh1zYLUStota21CqRXNidaqx16qVVap1XqriBqlQvL9aagN4Yg2whDTK0sdqLQZpAFG2irq427g9Ymi0HKuQcFWLQTg9leB%2BA4FoUgqBOBOMsNYGpGwtgDV2DwUgBBNC1tWNZEA9kNCqiVFIAAHJIHVs7ZRcCVLsDQ0h60cEkE2kdbbOC8AUCADQQ6R2rDgLAJAaB8R0FiOQSgV7kg3riIcQwwAuBruPTQWgrJD0QCiLuqIoQmjok4IOq9bBBAAHkGC0BAy23gWAeVGHEPB0g%2BBrjdChIe1DU4ugmW2IOvaNRQO8FoHgKIaJiDog8FgEjQ6fQsFPXwAwEkABqeBMAAHdINOjo/wQQIgxDsCkDIQQigVDqFQ7oQVBgjAoGsNYfQ5HD2wDHCANERhMAKAhLsUgUI4gEGIOZayUc20MkyNhgAtKGe2pgu2WDMEwA9NRoSZBcAwdwng2h6GCHMUo5Q9CpHSHULIXnciCqC4UBgAx/OLGqLUHoMxJh%2BEFZ0bo9QZgxaGBUWwSWwspdy30LLCwKirCZr24T9HMAEdrfoBtO7UPto4KoWdCRLMJEkBFWT7N32qinbqiAnanI2GOLgQgcc9gmo8Ne%2Bgs5JvLF4MO%2BDpnx2SCVH12d9kuD2SVDOsws6NAJCVEkTd27SDNtbU1g9R6T3LbrZwMwvBGMevO7uq7t2tCmf0%2BkZwkggA%3D%3D)

---

I reported this bug [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/very-inconsistent-behaviour-of-constexpr/1622695?space=62&entry=myfeedback).

Comment: Can you share your godbolt link. Thanks!

Comment: Which line(s) do those errors belong to?

Comment: @Klaus I added the links.

Comment: @NathanOliver on the line of the function declaration.

Comment: This is likely a MSVC bug. As a workaround you can move lambda out of function.

Comment: BTW: Is the lambda constexpr and use iostream?

Comment: @Genjutsu I thought about this, but the nice thing about the lambda is that it can call the function recursively, so 1 function. If I add another function I also have to add a forward declaration, so 3 functions and polluting the space a bit. But it adds up for many of these kind of functions.